# How to visually interpret Augmented Dickey-Fuller test results between two time series?

Tags: stationarity, augmented-dickey-fuller

Time-series #1 and #2 are daily reported disease cases in the Central vs. Southern regions, respectively. The p-values from the Augmented Dickey-Fuller test is less than 5% for #1 and more than 5% for #2. So that means Time-series #1 is non-stationary while Time-series #2 is stationary.

[image]

Visually examining the two graphs, it seems they don't have a trend, but #1 seems to have a stronger seasonality component than #2, is it the reason why #1 is deemed non-stationary while #2 as stationary from the Augmented Dickey-Fuller test?

Comment: Note that none of these series has a unit root, so there is no need for an ADF test to begin with. Having said that, you can still ask the questions you have asked as a theoretical exercise.

Comment: How did you determine that "none of these series has a unit root"?

Comment: These are counts that can never go below zero, while a unit-root process has a nonzero probability of crossing any level, zero included. Plus daily case counts are unlikely to be cumulative sums of anything, the latter being a defining trait of a unit-root process.

Comment: So, you mean, time-series of count case are all, by default, non-stationary. Can you elaborate on "unlikely to be cumulative sums of anything"? Wouldn't it be a cumulative sum of the infectious disease transmission process which is based on the number of hosts and vectors' presence in a location?

Comment: No, I absolutely do not mean that time series of count cases are all, by default, non-stationary. I mean that they cannot have a unit root (though there may be cases where a model with a unit root could be a decent approximation). Regarding the other part, a unit root process is a cumulative sum of another process. Counts today are not a cumulative sum of all previous counts.